Node.js で GCP の Cloud Functions から Firestore のデータを取得する方法が分からない
GCPのCloud FunctionsからFirestoreのデータを取得する方法について、公式ドキュメント等を参照していますが、わからずにいます。
しかしながら、Firestoreの使用状況タブでは読み取りカウントが増えているので疎通自体はできているかと思われます。
該当コード
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue, Filter } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');
initializeApp({credential: applicationDefault()});
const db = getFirestore();
const docRef = db.collection('User').doc('data');
const doc = await docRef.get()
 .catch(err => {console.error(err);});
console.log("Document data:", doc.data());

エラーメッセージ
Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: 
    at callErrorFromStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:193:76)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:360:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:323:181)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/resolving-call.js:129:78
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)


わたしもこれで２日間ほどスタックしていましたが、こちらの書き込みで解決しました
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2563#issuecomment-2228809974
データベース名(id)を指定して初期化が必要でした。
DBが１つの場合は指定は必要ないはずなのですが、なぜこうなったかは自分もわからないです。
getFirestore(<database_id>)


検証が遅くなりましたが、こちら私の環境でも試してみたところうまくいきました。ありがとうございます。公式にも載ってないのは謎ですが、、ｗ

この問題は解決しましたか？
私も解決できずにいます。
以下のスレッドでこの問題について会話をしています。公式からサポートを受けられるかもしれません。よろしければご確認ください。
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/2563
あなたの情報も参考にさせていただきました。ありがとうございます。

反応が遅れ申し訳ございません。情報共有いただきありがとうございます。
現在も解決しておらず、結局はFireStoreの利用を断念してしまいました、、。
参考のリンクも適宜チェックさせていただきたいと思います。
